# What is an Artifact?

Tags: maven, artifact

Recently I came across with the term '**artifact**' in related to maven build tool...

Can someone please explain what it's meant by '**artifact**' in software industry and specifically in maven.

Comment: Isn't that similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487485/what-is-maven-artifact ? It also includes an answer for "general software terms" artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven organizes it's build in projects.
An `artifact` in maven is a resource generated by a maven project. Each maven project can have exactly one `artifact` like a `jar, war, ear`, etc.
The project's configuration file `"pom.xml"` describes how the artifact is build, how unit tests are run, etc.
Commonly a software project build with maven consists of many maven-projects that build artifacts (e.g. jars) that constitute the product.
E.g.

```
Root-Project   // produces no artifact, simply triggers the build of the other projects
  App-Project  // The application, that uses the libraries
  Lib1-Project // A project that creates a library (jar)
  Lib2-Project // Another library
  Doc-Project  // A project that generates the user documentation from some resources
```

Maven artifacts are not limited to java resources. You can generate whatever resource you need. E.g. documentation, project-site, zip-archives, native-libraries, etc.