# Clarification on what an "artifact" means

Tags: software-design, artifacts

I've read many definitions of "artifact" as it pertains to the IT / software world.

After reading the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development)) and this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130282/what-is-an-artifact), I'm still very confused.

Would it be fair to say that when you uninstall software, any pieces left behind are considered artifacts?  (Files, registry entries, database records, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be fair to say that when you uninstall software, any pieces
>   left behind are considered artifacts?

No. The term "artifact", in a software context, means (loosely) "all the stuff created during the development process". What is left behind after you clean up is, well, some stuff, usually unwanted (unlike in archeology).

Comment: What are some examples of stuff that is left behind during the dev process?

Comment: I disagree. I think it is fair to call "artifacts" the pieces left behind. Artifacts can be anything, including those pieces. But I agree that it is more related to stuff regarding development process. It depends a lot on the context of use.

Comment: @kp950 - take the throwaway prototyping for instance - each new version leaves the old one behind in the dev process - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping#Throwaway_Prototyping

Comment: whenever I hear a developer say something about artifacts, it seems to me that they are referring to "leftovers" that are produced as a result of using the software.  So it seems like I was kind of right.

Comment: @darlinton saying "any pieces left behind are considered artifacts" implies in my opinion that the rest is not. But yes, that could be interpreted differently, I guess.

Comment: @kp950 no, "artifacts" are not **specifically** leftovers.

Comment: artifacts are not leftovers; they are the outcomes of some process.