# Eclipse Android SVN Project with other library

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, google-play-services

I have main project. This project uses two projects(facebook sdk and google play services). This two projects is library. How can I do that when you import the project all the libraries imported with it regardless of the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. The problem is how to libraries. The fact that the relative paths in Windows and Mac OS (Unix) a little bit different from each other. I put all the libraries in the project and link the them. The file project.properties little changed and went like this:

> android.library.reference.3=/holoeverywhere
>   android.library.reference.1=/facebook
>   android.library.reference.2=/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

Just begin to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). When You would like add some new library to your project, just add dependency to artifact to pom.xml file. See this links([what is maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487485/what-is-maven-artifact) ,[maven quick start](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), [maven-android tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html)), maybe it will explain the idea of maven.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the **Facebook SDK** and the **google-play-service-lib** the best way to use them in your project is do as said on the corresponding official pages.

1. Open each project in your workspace
2. Go to your project **properties**, then **Android** from the right list
3. Add both google and facebook projects (the ones of the point 1) to the **Library** list

Comment: This method does not work, because each project requires importing knit prescribe ways of libraries in the project settings should be applied.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Both the facebook and google projects don't require anything to do in order to use them.

Comment: I need to in the repository was my project with two libraries, that the employer is able to import the project itself and not re-connect these two libraries (not to prescribe them in the project settings). I understand that Maven is the only right decision.