# What is artifacts.xml in DAS 3.0.1

Tags: java, wso2, complex-event-processing

In the path C:\wso2\wso2das-3.0.1\repository\components there is a artifacts.xml file.

What is the function of this file?

Can I modify this file for add new libreries that I use for extend SIDDHI?, for example:

```
jaxrs-api-3.0.2.Final.jar
resteasy-client-3.0.2.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.2.Final.jar
javax.json-1.0.4.jar
javax.json-api-1.0.jar
```

My problem is Siddhi not recognize a JAR that contain this libreries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifacts.xml file is used by the Eclipse 'p2' install system to describe a repository of installable artifacts in the product. (This is described in [What is artifacts.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371134/what-is-artifacts-xml)).

You can write the siddi extensions as mentioned in the https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Writing+a+Custom+Function and drop the JAR to dropins folder. There is no need to refer the libraries you used to extend siddi in artifacts.xml file.

If you use any external dependencies you can copy those jar files in to $CEP_Home/repository/components/lib folder