# What are project artifacts in Maven exactly?

Tags: java, maven

When someone says "deploy artifact" or "project artifact" etc., how should I understand that?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2487485/1119381) there are a couple of answers that say that **usually** it's the jar but I want to be certain. Is that how I should understand that when reading about artifacts in a book or post?

Answer (score 1):

It is `.jar` file which is a result of maven build