# What does the word "Artifact" means when it is mentioned in during software development? Is it a source-code or document or can be both?

Tags: artifact

I am quite confused a bit when sometime people say the word "artifact". For example, please show me the artifact. Anyone could give me an example what the artifact mean and when we should say it? Why don't say that document or this library or something clearer. and What is the difference between artifact and tool?

Thanks in advance

---

Updated
Let me answer my question. After research in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development) , I can conclude that the word artifact is just some output during software development of each phase. For example, during collecting user's requirement, the artifact may be a document like user requirement specification.

During coding a program, the artifact might be output - that you workout like - source code that you will deliver or use in another phase such as code review and testing.

Hope my answer will help anyone who uncertain the meaning of this word.
Regards.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. This is an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please use Google and Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Maven artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487485/what-is-a-maven-artifact)

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my question. After research in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development) , I can conclude that the word artifact is just some output during software development of each phase. For example, during collecting user's requirement, the artifact may be a document like user requirement specification.

During coding a program, the artifact might be output - that you workout like - source code that you will deliver or use in another phase such as code review and testing.

Hope my answer will help anyone who uncertain the meaning of this word.
Regards.